# How to parallelize a function for a package in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I would like to parallelize a portion of a package I am working on. Which packages and what syntax should I use to make the package flexible and usable on different architectures? My problem sits in a single `sapply()` call as shown in this mock code:

```
.heavyStuff <- function(x) { 
   # do a lot of work
   Sys.sleep(1)
}

listOfX <- 1:20

userFunc1 <- function(listOfX) {    
  res <- sapply(listOfX, .heavyStuff)
  return(res)
}
```

Based on different guides, I have concocted the following:

```
userFunc2 <- function(listOfX, dopar.arg=2) {
  if(requireNamespace("doParallel")) {
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(dopar.arg)
    res <- foreach(i=1:length(listOfX)) %dopar% {
       .heavyStuff(listOfX[[i]])
    }
    names(res) <- names(listOfX)
  } else {
    res <- sapply(listOfX, .heavyStuff)
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Questions:

1. Can I safely use such a code in a package? Will it work well on a range of platforms?
2. Is there a way to avoid the `foreach()` construct? I'd much prefer to use a sapply- or lapply-like function. However, the constructs in the parallel library appear to be much more platform specific.
3. The above code doesn't work if `dopar.arg==NULL`, even though [the introduction to doParallel says that](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) without any arguments "you will get three workers and on Unix-like systems
   you will get a number of workers equal to approximately half the number of cores on your system."

Answer (score 3):

As the author of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework, I suggest that you have a look at the [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package, e.g.

```
library(future.apply)
userFunc2 <- function(listOfX) {    
  res <- future_sapply(listOfX, .heavyStuff)
  return(res)
}
```

The default is that things runs sequentially, but if the *user* wishes, they can use whatever parallel future backend they'd like, e.g.

```
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)    # parallel on local machine - all cores by default

library(future.batchtools)
plan(batchtools_sge)  # parallel on an SGE compute cluster

library(future)
plan(sequential)      # sequentially
```

The design pattern is that you decide *what* to parallelize whereas the user *how* to parallelize.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. It seems quite intuitive and really flexible. The only drawback I see is that allowing the user to provide additional arguments to the `plan()` will need extra code (I already use `...` for something else). Is there much overhead when running sequential `future_sapply` instead of `sapply`?

Comment: The idea of leaving it to the user to control `plan()` is mainly because as a package developer/maintainer you cannot really know what compute resources the user have available.  Also, you cannot predict what new parallel backends may be available in the future.  (This idea is not set in stone, and can be worked around, but it's a good design goal).

Comment: About overhead in `future_sapply()` vs `sapply()` when `plan(sequential)`: First, the objective is to keep this at a minimum. Having said this, there might be room for improvement (haven't pushed optimization that far yet).  Some overhead goes into automatic identification of global variables, so if you know that as a developer you can specify those manually (argument `future.globals`).  Also, as a rule of thumb, if there's code that's work parallelizing, then it means that there is a substantial processing time involved, and in such cases the added overhead should relatively small.

Comment: No, I totally get it why you need to leave the plan to the user; this is not different from my original solution (dopar.arg). The only problem is that I need more than one parameter (and that their names are not known, as they depend on the plan) to pass through to my function (whereas in the foreach %dopar% solution it is enough to pass only one argument).

Comment: So, your foreach example assumes parallelization on local machine only.  If that's all you want to support you can always pass through `nworkers` to call `plan(multiprocess, workers = nworkers)`.  However, if you do, you need to make sure to undo your `plan()` setting so that you don't mess with/override what the user has already set for other purposes. See also https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/263